# How do you create a legend for a contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, contour

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere! I found a discussion [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg08735.html), but trying this I get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
>>> z = x + y
>>> cs = plt.contourf(x,y,z,levels=[2,3])
>>> cs.collections[0].set_label('test')
>>> plt.legend()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2791, in legend
    ret =  gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4475, in legend
    self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._init_legend_box(handles, labels)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 627, in _init_legend_box
    handlebox)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 110, in __call__
    handlebox.get_transform())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 352, in create_artists
    width, height, fontsize)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 307, in get_sizes
    size_max = max(orig_handle.get_sizes())*legend.markerscale**2
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

**EDIT**: I'm looking for something like this:

[image: kamland solar delta chi-squared map]

Comment: A legend on a `contourf` makes no sense to me. Do you mean `colorbar`?

Comment: I've updated my question with an example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is a way to both label the contour lines from a `contour()` plot and label the filled regions from a `contourf()` plot.

Comment: Also, I get the same error when trying to label a `contour()` plot.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can create proxy artists to make the legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
cs = plt.contourf(x,y,z,levels=[2,3,4,6])

proxy = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1,fc = pc.get_facecolor()[0]) 
    for pc in cs.collections]

plt.legend(proxy, ["range(2-3)", "range(3-4)", "range(4-6)"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib has also support for hatched contours, which you could include by changing the proxy to `proxy = [pylab.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=pc.get_facecolor()[0], hatch=pc.get_hatch()) for pc in im.collections]`

Comment: Since the `collections` attribute was deprecated at Matplotlib v3.8, this should be updated with something like `proxy = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=fc) for fc in cs.get_facecolors()]`

Answer (score 61):

You could also do it directly with the lines of the contour, without using proxy artists.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)



# Create a simple contour plot with labels using default colors.  The
# inline argument to clabel will control whether the labels are draw
# over the line segments of the contour, removing the lines beneath
# the label
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')

labels = ['line1', 'line2','line3','line4',
           'line5', 'line6']
for i in range(len(labels)):
    CS.collections[i].set_label(labels[i])

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

Will produce:

[image: figure with legend and labels]

However, you might also want to look into annotations for your own need. In my opinion it will give you a more fine grained control on where and what you write on the image, here is the same example with some annotation:

```
### better with annotation, more flexible
plt.figure(2)
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')

plt.annotate('some text here',(1.4,1.6))
plt.annotate('some text there',(-2,-1.5))
```

[image: Figure with annotations]

Comment: I wanted to add, you can use the values of the contours with `for i, label in enumerate(CS.cvalues): CS.collections[i].set_label(label)`

Comment: `set_label()` does not render correctly with matplotlib 3.5.2. Use solutions below or `legend_elements()`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57030843/8500357) to make it less manual:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
levels=[2,3,4,6]
cs = plt.contourf(x,y,z,levels=levels)

proxy = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1,fc = pc.get_facecolor()[0]) 
    for pc in cs.collections]

plt.legend(proxy, [f"{lower:2.1f} - {upper:2.1f}" for lower, upper in zip(levels[:-1], levels[1:])])
plt.show()
```

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: Since the `collections` attribute was deprecated at Matplotlib v3.8, this should be updated with something like `proxy = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=fc) for fc in cs.get_facecolors()]`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `legend_elements` method, which will work for both filled and unfilled contours:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cs_filled = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=[2, 3, 4, 6])
handles_filled, labels = cs_filled.legend_elements()

cs_unfilled = ax.contour(x, y, np.flip(z, axis=1), levels=[3, 4, 6])
handles_unfilled, labels = cs_unfilled.legend_elements()

ax.legend(handles_filled + handles_unfilled,
          ["range(2-3)", "range(3-4)", "range(4-6)", "3", "4", "6"],
          ncols=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57024194/6135182) but needed to go a bit beyond [HYRY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491152/6135182). To make a package user friendly I wanted `ax.legend()` to work without requiring users to pass any handles, which can be achieved by passing the label on to the proxy

```py
proxy = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc='red', label='some label')
```

and then adding the proxy to the axis' patches:

```py
ax.patches += [proxy]
```

(do `ax = plt.gca()` to get the current axis)

This is described in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57030414/6135182).