# How to create an ax.legend() method for contourf plots that doesn't require passing of legend handles from a user?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, contour

## Desired feature

I would like to be able to call

```py
ax.legend()
```

on an axis containing a `contourf` plot and *automatically* get the legend (see plot below for an example).

## More Detail

I know how to create legend entries for `contourf` plots using proxies, see code below and which is already discussed [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491152/6135182). However, I would be interested in a solution where the final call to `axes[0][-1].legend()` does not require any handles being passed.

The  plot generation (more complex plots than in this example) is happening in a package and the user will have access to `fig` and `axes` and depending on the plots might prefer some axis over the others to plot the legend in. It would be nice if the call to `ax.legend()` could be simple and would not require the use of proxies and explicit passing of handles. This works automatically for normal plots, scatter plots, hists, etc., but `contourf` does not accept `label` as a kwarg and does not come with its own handle so I need to create a proxy (Rectangle patch in this case).

**But how could I attach/attribute/... the proxy alongside a label to the `contourf` plot or to the `axes` such that `ax.legend()` can automatically access them the way it does for other types of plots?**

## Example Image

[image]

## Example Code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


########################
# not accessed by User #
########################

def basic_cmap(color):
    return LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(color, ['#ffffff', color])
cmap1 = basic_cmap('C0')
cmap2 = basic_cmap('C1')

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
mvn1 = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=[4, 4])
mvn2 = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=[6, 7])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
Z1 = [[mvn1.pdf([x1, x2]) for x1 in x] for x2 in x]
Z2 = [[mvn2.pdf([x1, x2]) for x1 in x] for x2 in x]
Z1 = Z1 / np.max(Z1)
Z2 = Z2 / np.max(Z2)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
for i, row in enumerate(axes):
    for j, ax in enumerate(row):
        cont1 = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z1, [0.05, 0.33, 1], cmap=cmap1, alpha=0.7)
        cont2 = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z2, [0.05, 0.33, 1], cmap=cmap2, alpha=0.7)


###################################
# User has access to fig and axes #
###################################

proxy1 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=cmap1(0.999), ec=cmap1(0.33), alpha=0.7, linewidth=3)
proxy2 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=cmap2(0.999), ec=cmap2(0.33), alpha=0.7, linewidth=3)

# would like this without passing of handles and labels
axes[0][-1].legend(handles=[proxy1, proxy2], labels=['foo', 'bar'])  


plt.savefig("contour_legend.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It pretty rare to see contours with a legend, so no there is not automatic way to call legend.  How would legend know which contours to put in the legend.  Many people call contour with hundreds of levels.

Comment: I know this could not be done for general types of contour plots. However, in astronomy and cosmology it is _very common_ to see the 68% and 95% contours for multiple data sets or multiple theoretical models to see how well they agree/disagree. So this kind of forms a subgroup of contour plots used to plot multiple posterior "blobs" in one plot. Could this maybe be turned into a new plot command inheriting most of `plt.contourf`'s features but with a different treatment of legends where a new standard legend handle is provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I dappled a bit more and found a solution after all that's surprisingly simple, but I had to dig much deeper into `matplotlib.legend` to get the right idea. In `_get_legend_handles` it shows how it collects the handles:

```py
    for ax in axs:
        handles_original += (ax.lines + ax.patches +
                             ax.collections + ax.containers)
```

So all I was lacking was to pass the labels to the proxies and the proxies to `ax.patches`

## Example Code with Solution

#### changes

```py
        # pass labels to proxies and place proxies in loop
        proxy1 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=cmap1(0.999), ec=cmap1(0.33), 
                               alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, label='foo')
        proxy2 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=cmap2(0.999), ec=cmap2(0.33), 
                               alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, label='bar')

        # pass proxies to ax.patches
        ax.patches += [proxy1, proxy2]


###################################
# User has access to fig and axes #
###################################

# no passing of handles and labels anymore
axes[0][-1].legend()
```

#### full code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


########################
# not accessed by User #
########################

def basic_cmap(color):
    return LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(color, ['#ffffff', color])
cmap1 = basic_cmap('C0')
cmap2 = basic_cmap('C1')

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
mvn1 = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=[4, 4])
mvn2 = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=[6, 7])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
Z1 = [[mvn1.pdf([x1, x2]) for x1 in x] for x2 in x]
Z2 = [[mvn2.pdf([x1, x2]) for x1 in x] for x2 in x]
Z1 = Z1 / np.max(Z1)
Z2 = Z2 / np.max(Z2)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
for i, row in enumerate(axes):
    for j, ax in enumerate(row):
        cont1 = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z1, [0.05, 0.33, 1], cmap=cmap1, alpha=0.7)
        cont2 = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z2, [0.05, 0.33, 1], cmap=cmap2, alpha=0.7)

        # pass labels to proxies and place proxies in loop
        proxy1 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=cmap1(0.999), ec=cmap1(0.33), 
                               alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, label='foo')
        proxy2 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=cmap2(0.999), ec=cmap2(0.33), 
                               alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, label='bar')

        # pass proxies to ax.patches
        ax.patches += [proxy1, proxy2]


###################################
# User has access to fig and axes #
###################################

# no passing of handles and labels anymore
axes[0][-1].legend()  


plt.savefig("contour_legend_solved.png")
plt.show()
```

This produces the same image as shown in the question.

Sorry, was able to come up with a solution on my own after all, but maybe this will be helpful for someone else in the future.