# How can I reduce the amount of decimals in contour plot legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to get just one decimal place for the legend. The data which the plot is based on (w_field) has values with 8 decimal places.

```
w_field = np.genfromtxt('w_field.dat') 
CV = plt.contour(w_field)
x,Vel = CV.legend_elements()
plt.legend(x,Vel, title= 'Vertical velocity (m/s)', fontsize= 10, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left') 
plt.xlabel('Nx')
plt.ylabel('Ny')
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a legend for a contour plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490302/how-do-you-create-a-legend-for-a-contour-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi  The linked solutions are not suited for this case.  The first solution is for filled contours. The second uses `clabel` which isn't suitable for short contours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`CV.legend_elements()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.ContourSet.legend_elements) accepts a formatting parameter, which should be a function returning a formatted string. Here is an example, showing the difference with the default formatting.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

w_field = np.random.randn(60, 100).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0) / 50
CV = plt.contour(w_field)
x, Vel = CV.legend_elements()
legend1 = plt.legend(x, Vel, title='Default formatting', fontsize=10, bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1.02), loc='upper left')
x, Vel = CV.legend_elements(str_format=lambda x: f'{x:.1f}')
plt.legend(x, Vel, title='With formatting function', fontsize=10, bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 0), loc='lower left')
plt.gca().add_artist(legend1)  # matplotlib removes the legend when a second legend is created, here it is added again
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Even the [official example from the documents](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_hatching.html) show this strange formatting.

Comment: Great answer! It looks even nicer, if you format the string like this: `x, Vel = CV.legend_elements(str_format=lambda x: f'{x: .1f}')`

Comment: @Scotty1-  Something must be escaping me. You are just adding a space after the colon? Does that make a difference?

Comment: @JohanC Yep, it introduces a blank for positive numbers, such that positive and negative numbers are aligned at the first digit.

Comment: @Scotty1- OK, didn't know about that one.  Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work in this case, because the `legend_elements` of `plt.contour` forces a TeX rendering, always adding `'$x = ...$'` around the number. Further, the TeX minus sign is much wider than one space.

Comment: Oh right, somehow the TeX rendering was faulty. A restart now reproduces the behaviour you describe. In this case, replacing the blank with an explicit plus sign will make the formatting nicer: `x, Vel = CV.legend_elements(str_format=lambda x: f'{x:+.1f}')`. Unluckily I don't know of any built-in TeX command to make a spacing of the correct size instead of a plus. In Latex I'd use SIunitx or align env. for this purpose, but implementing it in matplotlib is quite complicated...

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
w_field = np.genfromtxt('w_field.dat') 
CV = ax.contour(w_field)
x,Vel = CV.legend_elements()
plt.legend(x,Vel, title= 'Vertical velocity (m/s)', fontsize= 10, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left') 
plt.xlabel('Nx')
plt.ylabel('Ny')

leg = ax.get_legend()

for lbl in leg.get_texts():
    label_text = lbl.get_text()
    float_num = label_text.split()[2]
    new_text = f'X = {float(float_num):,.1f}'
    lbl.set_text(new_text)
```