# How do I plot boundary decisions of multiple classifiers in one figure?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot the decision boundary conditions for multiple decision grain boundary in the same figure

The code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis,QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier,BaggingClassifier,RandomForestClassifier,HistGradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier,ExtraTreesClassifier

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]
classifiers = [LogisticRegression(solver='sag',penalty='l2',multi_class='ovr',
            max_iter=25000,random_state=None,fit_intercept=True),
            LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
            QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(),
            DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf=1),
            BaggingClassifier(),
            RandomForestClassifier(),
            AdaBoostClassifier(),
            HistGradientBoostingClassifier(),
            VotingClassifier(estimators=[('rfc',RandomForestClassifier()),
                                         ('dtc',DecisionTreeClassifier())],voting ='soft'),
            ExtraTreesClassifier()]

for classifier in classifiers:
    classifier.fit(X,iris.target)
    disp = DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(classifier, X, response_method="predict", xlabel=iris.feature_names[0], ylabel=iris.feature_names[1], alpha=0.5)
    disp.ax_.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=iris.target, edgecolor="k")

plt.show()
```

I did not get the result that I want, I need those plots in the same figure.

Can someone help me in this case?

Comment: @medium-dimensional sure i will, wait a sec

Comment: @medium-dimensional is it ok now?

Comment: @medium-dimensional can you also tell me how would someone add a legend with y categories, on my data set it is either 0 or 1

Comment: Could you please make sure the code reproduces the image that you are getting? It's throwing an error *NameError: name 'DecisionTreeClassifier' is not defined*.

Comment: @medium-dimensional in this case, if it is possible to add legends based on the y categroies, this would be fine, i guess i forgot to import other classifiers

Comment: @medium-dimensional i have edited the code with the imported classifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the decision boundaries of different classifiers in one figure, make sure to pass the argument `ax` in [`DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.html#sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator):

```
# Assuming there are 10 classifiers
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=2)
ax = ax.T.flatten()
i = 0

for classifier in classifiers:

    classifier.fit(X,iris.target)
    disp = DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(classifier, 
    X, response_method="predict", 
    xlabel=iris.feature_names[0], ylabel=iris.feature_names[1],
    alpha=0.5, ax=ax[i])

    disp.ax_.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=iris.target, edgecolor="k")
    
    # Refer to next Axes in a 5 * 2 grid created by plt.subplots
    i += 1
    
    # To get labels for contour plots
    labels = np.unique(iris.target)
    proxy = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1,fc = pc.get_facecolor()[0]) for pc in disp.surface_.collections]
    disp.ax_.legend(proxy, labels)

plt.show()
```

This gives:
[image]

This answer was motivated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491152/7789963) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72485993/7789963).

Comment: could you add a code to show the legend of the categories?

Comment: yes, the labels of the categories

Comment: @alamazahreh You can see that labels doesn't have exact colors as of contours, so that needs to be fixed. Feel free to unaccept this answer. ;)

Comment: this is exactly what i want!

Comment: yes, you are right